# Search box doesn't fit in header area

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, css, search

See screenshot below for issue, or look to the top of the screen.

[image]

Comment: what browser/version/OS are you using? I can't reproduce this in Chrome or Firefox

Comment: @Jin this is repro to me at FF 27.0.1 Windoze 7 SP 1, both main site and meta

Comment: Main site and meta, IE9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I pushed a fix for this to our dev server. The change will be on live site after our next production build.